# <machine> in launch file does not work?

Tags: roslaunch, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch the turtlebot_rviz_navigation from a launch file using the machine tag.  The launch file exists on the robot and rviz will be run on a remote computer.  Both have ROS installed and both can ssh into the other without any problems.
Here is my definition of the machine and the node:

```
<machine name="comp" address="comp@192.168.1.11" user="comp" env-loader="/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh" />
          <node machine="comp" name="view_navigation" pkg="turtlebot_rviz_launchers" type="view_navigation.launch" output="screen" launch-prefix="xterm -e" />
```

/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh in the remote computer has the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh
exec "$@"
```

When I run the launch file I get the error: "cannot resolve host address for machine [comp@192.168.1.11 The traceback for the exception was written to the log file"

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229136/%3Cmachine%3E-in-launch-file-does-not-work?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Address should just be your IP address, no need for the username.

---

Originally posted by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) with karma: 194 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
I get the error:
remote[192.168.1.11-0]: failed to launch on comp:
192.168.1.11 is not in your SSH known_hosts file.
Please manually: ssh comp@192.168.1.11
then try roslaunching again.

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-03-15**:
Do as the error message says. After you ssh in the first time, it'll get added to your .ssh/known_hosts file. You can also manually add it yourself.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
I ssh'ed into comp@192.168.1.11 then exited and relaunched and got the same error.  I have ssh'ed into my remote computer before.  How do I manually add the IP to the known hosts file?  "nano ~/.ssh/known_hosts" shows two illegible lines.

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
Okay, I successfully added the address to my known_hosts file but now I get the error "error launching on [192.168.1.11-0, uri http://comp:57183/]: Name or service not known" for the node that I am trying to run through the ssh.

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-03-15**:
Hm. That doesn't seem right. It should look like ["username"-0, uri http://"ip":11311/]. Are you sure you put everything in the right order?

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
Ah, I was trying to launch a launch file as a node instead of as an include.  However, now I am getting the problem that I can't launch a launch file from a remote computer.  The include argument only looks for files locally.  Is there anyway to include a file from a remote computer?

**Comment by [alee](https://answers.ros.org/users/26002/alee/) on 2016-03-15**:
I don't think so. However, you can launch nodes on a remote computer so you can launch a file locally that launches remote nodes. An example would be here: https://github.com/PR2/pr2_robot/blob/indigo-devel/pr2_bringup/config/kinect2_bridge.launch

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-15**:
I tried to create a similar workaround by writing a .py node on the remote computer that will execute the desired file.  Then I try to launch that .py node from the launch file using the  declaration include the machine tag but I get the "Name or service not known" error